# Python Requests PUT not working, but cURL does

Tags: python, rest, curl, https, python-requests

I'm looking to `PUT` data to the [Pipeline Deals API](https://www.pipelinedeals.com/developers/api) in Python with [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), and though I get a `Response 200`, the data does not actually successfully `PUT`. When I make the exact same request with `cURL`, it does. Here's the Python code that doesn't work:

```
param = {'api_key': 'MY API KEY'}
url = "https://api.pipelinedeals.com/api/v3/companies/14634816.json"
r = requests.put(url, params=param, data="company[name]=Python")
print r
--> <Response [200]>
```

When I run this `cURL` code, it works:

```
curl --X PUT -d "company[name]=cURL" \
"https://api.pipelinedeals.com/api/v3/companies/14634816.json?api_key=SAME_API_KEY"
```

Am I missing something? Or is it possible I'm hitting a bug in the Requests library, such as around `https`?

Thanks!

Comment: try running curl with `--verbose` option and compare request headers with those in python requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change a bit into the URL:

```
url = "https://api.pipelinedeals.com/api/v3/companies/14634816.json?api_key=MY_API_KEY"
```

And then the params:

```
param = {"company[name]":"Python"}
```

Now to the `PUT`

```
r = requests.put(url, data=param)
```

Comment: Worked! I played around with it a little and it actually seems that the issue is not adding the API Key to the URL, but encoding the data as `{"company[name]":"Python"}`. So according to the [documentation](https://www.pipelinedeals.com/api/docs/request_response), one can PUT as either JSON or a string.Any idea how I would do it like this: `{'company':{'name':'Python'}}`?

Comment: Not sure, but may be something like this `{"company":{"name":"Python"}}` (if its json required).

Comment: Gotcha. That didn't work (or other variations of that), but I think `{"company[name]":"Python"}` should work fine. Thanks!